# Pandas non-numeric categorical dummy columns to single categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like following

```
test=pd.DataFrame( {'group':['v','w','x','y','z'],
                       'cat1':['a',np.nan,np.nan,'c',np.nan],
                       'cat2':[np.nan,'b','a',np.nan,np.nan],
                       'cat3':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'a'],
                      })
```

I wanted to make like following

```
| group | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 |
|-------|------|------|------|
|   v   |  a   | NaN  | NaN  |
|   w   | NaN  |  b   | NaN  |
|   x   | NaN  |  a   | NaN  |
|   y   |  c   | NaN  | NaN  |
|   z   | NaN  | NaN  |  a   |
```

to

```
| group | category | values |
|-------|----------|--------|
|   v   |   cat1   |   a    |
|   w   |   cat2   |   b    |
|   x   |   cat2   |   a    |
|   y   |   cat1   |   c    |
|   z   |   cat3   |   a    |
```

I tried using `idxmax` from another question in stackoverflow but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to convert "group" to the index, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to remove NaNs, then you're done:

```
test.set_index('group').stack()

group      
v      cat1    a
w      cat2    b
x      cat2    a
y      cat1    c
z      cat3    a
dtype: object
```

```
(test.set_index('group')
     .stack()
     .reset_index(name='values')
     .rename(columns={'level_1': 'categories'}))

  group categories values
0     v       cat1      a
1     w       cat2      b
2     x       cat2      a
3     y       cat1      c
4     z       cat3      a
```

NOTE: Does NOT sort the rows

---

Another option is using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), produces similar output:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(test, ['cat'], i=['group'], j='category')
   .dropna()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={'cat': 'values'}))

  group  category values
0     v         1      a
1     y         1      c
2     w         2      b
3     x         2      a
4     z         3      a
```

NOTE: Rows will be sorted by "category"

Comment: @Ch3steR really appreciate you deleting your answer, was not expected but definitely appreciated :-) Good to see decent folks here every now and then.

Comment: I previously used stack with very long code. Now your solution seem pretty slim and good specially second answer.

Comment: No problem two similar answer wouldn't help the community anyway. I posted it because I haven't seen your post else I wouldn't in the first place.  I feel proud I came with the same approach. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), drop the null values and sort on the `variable` column

```
test.melt("group", var_name="category").dropna().sort_values("variable", ignore_index=True)


    group   variable    value
0     v     cat1         a
1     y     cat1         c
2     w     cat2         b
3     x     cat2         a
4     z     cat3         a
```

Comment: I liked melt. But i don't need to sort. Thanks